# can't append string to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

```py
new_list = []

def calculatePermutations(sentence):
    permute = permutations(sentence)
    for i in permute:
        permutelist = i
        for j in permutelist:
            for z in range(len(i)):
                new_list.append("apple")
                print("it is printing")

print(new_list[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentence = keywords
    calculatePermutations(sentence)
```

I am trying to append some data from the function into the new_list but when i try to get that data from the list i am getting error:

`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Are you actually calling your `calculatePermutations` function at any point? If not then `new_list` will not be fill with anything, sot the `print(new_list[0])` will fail.

Comment: Yes , i have called the function at the end of my code and it get executed and even the line below `new_list.append("apple")` which is `print("it is printing")` is getting printed

Comment: Please update your question to show how you are calling your function.

Comment: updated.. kindly check now

Comment: Ok, so why are you doing that when it give you an error?

Comment: Did you mean to move the line: `print(new_list[0])` as the last line of the script?

Comment: i am still unsure why the above code is not working as this code is working `print("it is printing")'  while the line before it which is to append in to the list is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your function, so that you define `new_list` within it and then return `new_list` at the end:

```py
from itertools import permutations

def calculatePermutations(sentence):
    new_list = []
    permute = permutations(sentence)
    for i in permute:
        permutelist = i
        for j in permutelist:
            for z in range(len(i)):
                new_list.append("apple")
    return new_list

# call the function
mylist = calulatePermutations("Blah")

print(mylist[0])  # output should be apple
```

Note that in this case `mylist` will contain 384 instances of the string `"apple"`.

Comment: I can see that this will work, but how do you know that this is what the OP wants?